# Separate "other" flags by moderators from those by non-moderators in the flag dashboard

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderator-tools

Right now, 'other' flags are grouped together under one heading in the sidebar.

> [image]

Many mod teams - including the one for the site I moderate - use custom flags to mark content that should be followed up on, or to make notes, or for a variety of reasons. However, the weight of these flags in priority ends up pretty high, for what I surmise is due to three things: first, that it's an "other" flag; second, the flag weight of the moderator casting it; third, that these follow-up notes tend to intentionally linger a bit longer than normal, and are not necessarily immediately actionable.

This means that 'other' flags cast by moderators end up at the top of the priority list, which makes finding flags that actually need immediate attention a slightly more difficult task. As a result, the priority queue structure of the flag dashboard breaks down, because the assumptions for the heuristics it uses don't apply.

I'd like to see a feature that separates 'other' flags into two groups: ones cast by moderators, and ones cast by non-moderators. I think this would allow for easy separation of the flags that actually do require immediate attention.